# Subqueries in SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, group-concat

I need to `SELECT` from multiple tables to get a result table like the following:

```
+--------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
| itemID | level | studyPhraseString | meaningPhraseStrings |
+--------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
| 1      | 4     | la maison         | house                |
+--------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
| 2      | 3     | voler             | to fly,to steal      |
+--------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Note: `studyPhraseString` and `meaningPhraseStrings` should be concatenated strings made up of values from the `word` table.

**My tables:**

item

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
`itemID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`groupID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`studyLang` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`meaningLang` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`studyPhraseID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

meaning

```
CREATE TABLE `meaning` (
  `meaningID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `meaningPhraseID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `meaningIndex` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meaningID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

phrase

```
CREATE TABLE `phrase` (
  `phraseID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phraseLang` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`phraseID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

phrase_word

```
CREATE TABLE `phrase_word` (
  `phrase_wordID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phraseID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `wordID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `wordIndex` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`phrase_wordID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

status

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `statusID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nextReviewTime` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`statusID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

word

```
CREATE TABLE `word` (
  `wordID` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `string` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`wordID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have written the following SELECT statement:

```sql
SELECT item.itemID, status.level, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM word INNER JOIN phrase_word ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
INNER JOIN item AS subItem ON phrase_word.phraseID=subItem.studyPhraseID 
WHERE subItem.itemID=item.itemID
GROUP BY subItem.itemID
) AS studyPhraseString
FROM item INNER JOIN status ON item.itemID=status.itemID
WHERE item.groupID=5
ORDER BY status.statusID DESC
```

This works but does not include the `meaningPhraseString`. I can’t figure out **how to concat the words into phrases AND concat the phrases into one string** separated by ,

I have tried nested GROUP_CONCAT clauses with no success (subquery returns more than 1 row):

### **The question**:

How should this statement be written to include `meaningPhraseStrings`? Thanks in advance.

PS: I'd like this to be a single query

**I have tried the following but it fails. Why? It has two levels of correlated queries.**

```
SELECT 
item.itemID, 
status.level, 
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex SEPARATOR ' ')
    FROM word INNER JOIN phrase_word ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
    INNER JOIN item AS subItem ON phrase_word.phraseID=subItem.studyPhraseID 
    WHERE subItem.itemID=item.itemID
    GROUP BY subItem.itemID
) AS studyPhraseString, 

(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meaningPhraseString SEPARATOR '.') 
    FROM (
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word.string ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex SEPARATOR ' ') AS meaningPhraseString
            FROM word INNER JOIN phrase_word ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
            INNER JOIN meaning ON phrase_word.phraseID=meaning.meaningPhraseID
            INNER JOIN item AS subItem ON meaning.itemID=subItem.itemID 
            
            WHERE subItem.itemID=item.itemID #This fails
            
            GROUP BY meaning.meaningPhraseID
        ) AS meaningPhraseString
    )
) AS meaningPhraseStrings

FROM item INNER JOIN status ON item.itemID=status.itemID
WHERE item.groupID=5
ORDER BY item.itemID DESC
```

**Sample data:**

```
INSERT INTO `status` VALUES (22,22,0,0),(23,23,0,0),(24,25,0,0),(25,24,0,0),(26,26,0,0);
INSERT INTO `item` VALUES (22,5,'fr','en',49),(23,5,'fr','en',48),(24,5,'fr','en',56),(25,5,'fr','en',50),(26,5,'fr','en',57);
INSERT INTO `meaning` VALUES (27,22,51,0),(28,23,52,0),(29,23,54,1),(30,24,59,0),(31,24,61,1),(32,25,53,0),(33,25,55,1),(34,26,58,0),(35,26,60,1);
INSERT INTO `phrase` VALUES (48,'fr'),(49,'fr'),(50,'fr'),(51,'en'),(52,'en'),(53,'en'),(54,'en'),(55,'en'),(56,'fr'),(57,'fr'),(58,'en'),(59,'en'),(60,'en'),(61,'en');
INSERT INTO `word` VALUES (46,'l\'autobus'),(47,'bus'),(48,'pourquoi'),(49,'comment'),(50,'why'),(51,'ça'),(52,'va?'),(53,'voler'),(54,'incroyable'),(55,'how'),(56,'is'),(57,'to'),(58,'are'),(59,'incredible'),(60,'that?'),(61,'you?'),(62,'fly'),(63,'amazing'),(64,'hi'),(65,'steal');
INSERT INTO `phrase_word` VALUES (86,49,46,0),(87,51,47,0),(88,48,48,0),(89,50,49,0),(90,52,50,0),(91,54,50,0),(92,50,51,1),(93,50,52,2),(94,57,53,0),(95,53,55,0),(96,56,54,0),(97,54,56,1),(98,53,58,1),(99,58,57,0),(100,59,59,0),(101,54,60,2),(102,53,61,2),(103,58,62,1),(104,61,63,0),(105,60,57,0),(106,55,64,0),(107,60,65,1);
```

### **Final answer**:

```
SELECT i.itemID, 
        s.level,
        sp.studyPhraseString,
        GROUP_CONCAT(mp.meaningPhraseString
                     SEPARATOR ', ') AS meaningPhraseStrings            
   FROM item AS i
   JOIN meaning AS m ON i.itemID = m.itemID
   JOIN status AS s ON i.itemID = s.itemID
   JOIN ( 
       SELECT subItem.studyPhraseID,
              GROUP_CONCAT(word.string 
                           ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex 
                           SEPARATOR ' ') AS studyPhraseString
         FROM word 
         JOIN phrase_word
           ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
         JOIN item AS subItem 
           ON phrase_word.phraseID=subItem.studyPhraseID 
     GROUP BY subItem.studyPhraseID
        ) AS sp ON i.studyPhraseID = sp.studyPhraseID   
   JOIN ( 
       SELECT meaning.meaningPhraseID,
              GROUP_CONCAT(word.string 
              ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex
              SEPARATOR ' ') AS meaningPhraseString
         FROM word 
         JOIN phrase_word ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
         JOIN meaning ON phrase_word.phraseID=meaning.meaningPhraseID
         JOIN item AS subItem ON meaning.itemID=subItem.itemID 
     GROUP BY meaning.meaningPhraseID
        ) AS mp ON m.meaningPhraseID = mp.meaningPhraseID
  GROUP BY i.itemID, s.level, sp.studyPhraseString
  ORDER BY i.itemID, s.level, sp.studyPhraseString
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` makes little or no sense in a query unless accompanied by a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I have added GROUP BY into the subqueries but it doesn't make any difference. I agree that there should be a GROUP BY.

Comment: I am trying to answer your question, but I don't understand your schema very well. Can you provide some sample table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be this:

> how to concat the words into phrases AND concat the phrases into one string

Let's break it down.  You need to join together five tables. Three of them are physical tables, namely `item`, `meaning`, and `status`.  From those tables you get the references to the result set items you need called itemID and level, and you get the relationship between items and their meanings.

The other two tables you need are virtual tables (that is, subqueries). One of these gives you your French language phrases, and the other gives you your English-language translations.

Let us create the two queries for the virtual tables. Let's put the words into phrases first. A query like this achieves that goal.

```
 SELECT subItem.studyPhraseID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(word.string 
                     ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex 
                     SEPARATOR ' ') AS studyPhraseString
   FROM word 
  INNER JOIN phrase_word ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
  INNER JOIN item AS subItem ON phrase_word.phraseID=subItem.studyPhraseID 
  GROUP BY subItem.studyPhraseID
```

This gives you a resultset table of phrase ID numbers and the phrases. Here's a SQL fiddle for this one based on your samples.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11ae2/9/0

Then, create a similar query giving you the `meaningPhraseString` values.

```
 SELECT meaning.meaningPhraseID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(word.string 
        ORDER BY phrase_word.wordIndex
        SEPARATOR ' ') AS meaningPhraseString
   FROM word 
  INNER JOIN phrase_word ON word.wordID=phrase_word.wordID
  INNER JOIN meaning ON phrase_word.phraseID=meaning.meaningPhraseID
  INNER JOIN item AS subItem ON meaning.itemID=subItem.itemID 
  GROUP BY meaning.meaningPhraseID
```

This gives a list of ids and meaning phrases. Here's the fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11ae2/6/0

So, we're going to need a five-way join (three physical tables and two subqueries) to get to our final result set. In summary, it will look like this:

```
 SELECT i.itemID, 
        s.level,
        sp.studyPhraseString,
        mp.meaningPhraseString            
   FROM item AS i
   JOIN meaning AS m ON i.itemID = m.itemID
   JOIN status AS s ON i.itemID = s.itemID
   JOIN ( 
           /* the studyPhrase subquery */ 
        ) AS sp ON i.studyPhraseID = sp.studyPhraseID   
   JOIN ( 
           /* the meaningPhrase subquery */ 
        ) AS mp ON m.meaningPhraseID = mp.meaningPhraseID
```

The trick here is that you can use a query (or virtual table) and a physical table interchangeably. So when you need to summarize a bunch of tables, you create a query to do that and then paste it into `JOIN (/*query*/) AS alias`.

Finally, you need to create the comma-joined strings (e.g. `to fly, to steal`) by adding yet another `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY` to your query.  The end result is then

```
 SELECT i.itemID, 
        s.level,
        sp.studyPhraseString,
        GROUP_CONCAT(mp.meaningPhraseString
                     SEPARATOR ', ') AS meaningPhraseStrings            
   FROM item AS i
   JOIN meaning AS m ON i.itemID = m.itemID
   JOIN status AS s ON i.itemID = s.itemID
   JOIN ( 
           /* the studyPhrase subquery */ 
        ) AS sp ON i.studyPhraseID = sp.studyPhraseID   
   JOIN ( 
           /* the meaningPhrase subquery */ 
        ) AS mp ON m.meaningPhraseID = mp.meaningPhraseID
  GROUP BY i.itemID, s.level, sp.studyPhraseString
  ORDER BY i.itemID, s.level, sp.studyPhraseString
```

And that is your query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11ae2/16/0  It definitely takes advantage of the *Structured* in *Structured Query Language.*

Comment: Thanks so far, I'll update the question with sample data in a moment.

Comment: I've written a query for meaningPhraseString now. I'd like to present my schema here in a better way but I can't think of a clear way to put it? Should I post pictures?

Comment: I have tried to combine the queries together but no luck. Could you please look at my attempt and help me.

Comment: Sample DATA?  Please?

Comment: I've added insert statements for sample data and the db export. I'm sorry it took so long.

Comment: OK. By the way, nice normalized schema!

Comment: Thank you so much! Finding materials that show how to do this sort of queries seems really difficult.

Comment: It's true it's hard to learn to do this stuff. The key insight is that physical tables and queries are peer entities and can be joined.